# Adding attachment to Slackbot

Tags: python, bots, slack-api, slack

I'm trying to add an attachment to a slack message via their API. I'm using the python wrapper they recommend. I can send and receive basic messages but when I try to add an attachment in the form of 2 buttons it fails. I have made a slack app and linked the bot as they state in their API. I've carefully reviewed the API and cannot figure out what is going on.

```
def process_message(message, channel):
    intro_msg = json.loads('{
                      "text": "What would you like to do?",
                      "attachments": [
                        {
                          "text": "Choose an action",
                          "fallback": "You are unable to choose an option",
                          "callback_id": "lunch_intro",
                          "color": "#3AA3E3",
                          "attachment_type": "default",
                          "actions": [
                            {
                              "name": "enroll",
                              "text": "Enroll",
                              "type": "button",
                              "value": "enroll"
                            },
                            {
                              "name": "leave",
                              "text": "Leave",
                              "type": "button",
                              "value": "leave"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }')
    r = sc.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=channel, attachments=intro_msg)
```

The response is only `{u'ok': False, u'error': u'no_text'}`

Comment: Instead of creating `intro_msg` as `dict` object with from `string`, can you tell me what do you see when you pass `dict` object directly?

Comment: have you finished it ? how to get response payload ?

Comment: I figured it out below. My payload had the `text` field in it. This needs to be separated out from the payload.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured it out.

The python wrapper separates out the payload.

```
intro_msg  = json.dumps([{"text":"Choose an action","fallback":"You are unable to choose an option","callback_id":"lunch_intro","color":"#3AA3E3","attachment_type":"default","actions":[{"name":"enroll","text":"Enroll","type":"button","value":"enroll"},{"name":"leave","text":"Leave","type":"button","value":"leave"}]}])

sc.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=channel, text="What would you like to do?", attachments=intro_msg, as_user=True)
```

My payload was all in attachments since that is how they format it in their API docs. The attachments needs to just be the array after the attachments key.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the basic simple example works.

Example:

```
from slackclient import SlackClient

slack_token = os.environ["SLACK_API_TOKEN"]
sc = SlackClient(slack_token)

sc.api_call(
  "chat.postMessage",
  channel="#python",
  text="Hello from Python! :tada:"
)
```

According to https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage and https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons#readying_your_application_for_message_buttons the attachments has to be an array. How about sending it as array:

```
json.loads('[{"text":"What would you like to do?","attachments":[{"text":"Choose an action","fallback":"You are unable to choose an option","callback_id":"lunch_intro","color":"#3AA3E3","attachment_type":"default","actions":[{"name":"enroll","text":"Enroll","type":"button","value":"enroll"},{"name":"leave","text":"Leave","type":"button","value":"leave"}]}]}]')
```

As there is no further magic involved but the requests module https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/blob/ddf9d8f5803040f0397d68439d3217d1e1340d0a/slackclient/_slackrequest.py I'd give it a try with the sending as array.